# icmp dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'struct icmp'

Tags: c++, c, linux

I got an error:

```
dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'struct ip'
138| u_int8_t icmp_Type = icmp_package->icmp_type;
```

I've made some research, found some similar topics on this, but nothing helped. The problem probably is with icmp.

The program works like `traceroute` in a Linux terminal.

None of these seem to work to fix it:

- adding `-D_GNU_SOURCE` to `gcc` command
- adding `__USE_BSD`

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Compiling on Linux with `gcc -std=c17`

```
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/ip_icmp.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int receive_from(int sockfd, char recipient[20], int PID, int TTL, char response[20]);

void print_as_bytes (unsigned char* buff, ssize_t length)
{
    for (ssize_t i = 0; i < length; i++, buff++)
        printf ("%.2x ", *buff);    
}


void print_row(int RCV_NUM, int avg, int TTL, char responses[3][20])
{
    if(TTL < 10)
        printf(" ");

    printf("%d", TTL);

    if(RCV_NUM == 0)
    {
        printf("*\n");
    } else {

        printf(" %s", responses[0]);

        if(strcmp(responses[0], responses[1]) != 0)
            printf(" %s", responses[1]);
        if(strcmp(responses[0], responses[2]) != 0 && strcmp(responses[1], responses[2]) != 0)
            printf(" %s", responses[2]);

        if(RCV_NUM < 3)
            printf("    ???\n");
        else 
            printf("    %d ms", avg);
    }
}


int receive(int sockfd, char recipient[20], int PID, int TTL)
{
    int DEST_REACHED = 0;
    char responses[3][20] = {"", "", ""};

    struct timeval time;
    gettimeofday(&time, NULL);
    long long start = ((long long)time.tv_sec * 1000) + (time.tv_usec / 1000);

    fd_set descriptors;
    FD_ZERO(&descriptors);
    FD_SET(sockfd, &descriptors);
    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = 1;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    int time_passed = 0;
    int which = 0;

    while(which < 3)
    {
        int ready = select (sockfd+1, &descriptors, NULL, NULL, &tv);

        if(ready < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "traceroute: select error: %s\n", strerror(errno)); 
            which++;
        }
        if(ready > 0)
        {
            gettimeofday(&time, NULL);
            long long timeNow = ((long long)time.tv_sec * 1000) + (time.tv_usec / 1000);
            time_passed += timeNow - start;

            int result = receive_from(sockfd, recipient, PID, TTL, responses[which]);
            if(result == -1)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "traceroute: Package missed\n");
                which++;
                continue;
            }
            if(result == 1)
            {
                DEST_REACHED = 1;
            }

            which++;

            if(which == 3) 
            { break; }
        }
        if(ready == 0)
        {
            which++;
        }
    }

    int avg;
    int RCV_NUM = 3;

    if(which < 3)
    {
        RCV_NUM = which;
    } else {
        avg = time_passed / 3;
    }

    print_row(RCV_NUM, avg, TTL, responses);

    return DEST_REACHED;
}

int receive_from(int sockfd, char recipient[20], int PID, int TTL, char response[20])
{
    struct sockaddr_in  sender; 
    socklen_t           sender_len = sizeof(sender);
    u_int8_t            buffer[IP_MAXPACKET];

    ssize_t packet_len = recvfrom (sockfd, buffer, IP_MAXPACKET, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&sender, &sender_len);
    if (packet_len < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "recvfrom error: %s\n", strerror(errno)); 
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char sender_ip_str[20]; 
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(sender.sin_addr), sender_ip_str, sizeof(sender_ip_str));
    printf ("Received IP packet with ICMP content from: %s\n", sender_ip_str);

    struct ip*          ip_header = (struct ip*) buffer;
    ssize_t             ip_header_len = 4 * ip_header->ip_hl;
    struct icmp*        icmp_package = (struct icmp*)((uint8_t *)ip_header + ip_header_len);

    u_int8_t icmp_Type = icmp_package->icmp_type;
    u_int8_t icmp_Code = icmp_package->icmp_code;

    //We reached the destination point
    if(icmp_Type == 0 && icmp_Code == 0)
    {
        if(icmp_package->icmp_hun.ih_idseq.icd_id == (u_int16_t) PID && icmp_package->icmp_hun.ih_idseq.icd_id == (u_int16_t) TTL)
        {
            inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(sender.sin_addr), response, 20);
            return 1;
        }
    }

    //Time Exceeded - we are not yet in the destination point
    if(icmp_Type == 11 && icmp_Code == 0)
    {
        struct ip*      ip_header_md = (struct ip *)((uint8_t *)icmp_package + 8);
        struct icmp*    icmp_package_md = (struct icmp *)((uint8_t *)ip_header_md + (*ip_header_md).ip_hl * 4);

        if(icmp_package_md->icmp_hun.ih_idseq.icd_id == (u_int16_t) PID && icmp_package_md->icmp_hun.ih_idseq.icd_id == (u_int16_t) TTL)
        {
            inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(sender.sin_addr), response, 20);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    //Błąd
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Your question title mentions `struct icmp` but the error message you showed says `struct ip`. Looking at your code you seem to be trying to dereference a `struct icmp`. Can you please paste the error message exactly as it's shown?

Comment: Can you show the error message(s) exactly as they appear at the console.  As far as I'm aware `struct icmp` *should* be defined in `netinet/ip_icmp.h` and you've included that already.

Comment: I tried to compile your code. While my local gcc version did not support gcc -std=c17, with clang - `clang-9 -std=c17 icmp.c` - I get same error. It seems to go away by adding `-D_GNU_SOURCE `  -  `clang-9 -std=c17 -D_GNU_SOURCE icmp.c`

Comment: ok, found a hidden gcc-8 compiler installation, see same behaviour as clang, adding `-D_GNU_SOURCE` fixes the compiler error